How do you use an excel match formula using the column name rather than the column letters ie: Column Named "Name" instead of F1:F3
I'm trying to use a match formula. Instead of referencing column F1:F3 for example, I want to use the Column name instead.
Here is the formula with the column letters.
 =IF(B4 = "Teacher","Not Apply",IF(B4="Student",HLOOKUP("Class",E1:G3,MATCH(B3,F1:F3,0),FALSE), "Not Found"))

I need to replace the F1:F3 with the column name, which is "Name".
I've tried using an HLOOKUP in place of the Column reference, but run into issues because it needs to know which value to return. The row that needs returned, depends on the value in Cell A3, but that changes each time I need to look something up, so I'm not sure how to reference it.

It is a bit hard for me to grasp the issue without more data, but is this what you're trying to get? =IF(B4 = "Teacher", "Not Apply", IF(B4 = "Student", HLOOKUP("Class", E1:G3, MATCH($B$3, INDEX(E1:G3, , MATCH($A$3, $E$1:$G$1, 0)), 0), FALSE)))

Yes it does, Thank you very much!! I had to swap out the $A$3, with the word "Name", as that Cell doesn't exist in my real data, but that's exactly what I needed.
